# Competing onTouchEvent handlers?

Tags: android, android-view, android-touch-event

I understand Views can decide to handle MotionEvent themselves by returning true in `onTouchEvent` when being passed a `ACTION_DOWN` event. If they return `true`, then they will receive all the subsequent `MOVE/UP/CANCEL` events. This is working fine.

What I would like to do is defer this decision to the `ACTION_MOVE` event. I have a ViewGroup containing a child and depending if scrolling horizontally or vertically, I would like the ViewGroup or Child to be responsible for handling the `MotionEvents`

Something like:

```
public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup{
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mDownX = event.getX();
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (Math.abs(event.getX() - mDownX) > THRESHOLD_X) {
                // I want all the future events to be forwarded to this ViewGroup
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyChild extend View {
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mDownY = event.getY();
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (Math.abs(event.getY() - mDownY) > THRESHOLD_Y) {
                // I want all the future events to be forwarded to this View
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is that possible ? Right now, only the ViewGroup will receive the `MOVE/UP/CANCEL`. I guess because it did not find a suitable child to forward the Views to.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I ended up doing this by overriding `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent()`. It's a bit cumbersome but doable. I can share the code if needed.